# Uploading image to folder and info to database using PHP/SQL

Tags: php, mysql, upload

I'm trying to upload a picture with a form in PHP so that the info is saved into the database but picture is saved into folder instead. I have the "$pic" variable as 'BLOB' but when I upload the database tells me that it's 0kb, and no picture in folder. I'm pretty new to PHP so I hope you understand what I meant :D Thx

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Insert car!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/newgame.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
            require_once "includes/connection.php";

            $target_dir = "img/";
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['pic']['name']);

            $car = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['car']);
            $descr = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['description']);
            $manuf = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['manuf']);
            $dist = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['dist']);
            $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['price']);
            $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
            $pic = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_FILES['pic']['name']);
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);

            mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO carlist (pic, car, descr, year, dist, price, seller) VALUES ('$pic', '$car', '$descr', '$price', '$manuf', '$dist', '$name')");

            echo "<p>The following car information was successfully added to database:</p>";
            echo "<p>\"$car\"</p>";
            echo "<p>Description: $descr</p>";
            echo "<p>Price: $price</p>";
            echo "<p>Manufacturer: $manuf</p>";
            echo "<p>Picture: $pic</p>";
            echo "<p>Name: $name</p>";
            echo "<p>Distance: $dist</p>";

            mysqli_close($con);

        ?>
        <br><br>
        <a href="newcar.html">Insert another car</a>
        <br>
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please not that it is "better practice" to save your images to the file server and save your image path to the database, than to actually store the image in the database.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: can you show html your form

Answer (score 0):

made some change try this code
if you get any error feel free to ask

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Insert car!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/newgame.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        require_once "includes/connection.php";

        $target_dir = "img/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['pic']['name']);

        $car = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['car']);
        $descr = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['description']);
        $manuf = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['manuf']);
        $dist = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['dist']);
        $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['price']);
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
        $pic = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_FILES['pic']['name']);


        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO carlist (pic, car, descr, year, dist, price, seller) VALUES ('$pic', '$car', '$descr', '$price', '$manuf', '$dist', '$name')");
        //Writes the photo to the server
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'], $target)) {

//Tells you if its all ok
            echo "The file " . basename($_FILES['pic']['name']) . " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
        } else {

//Gives and error if its not
            echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
        }

        echo "<p>The following car information was successfully added to database:</p>";
        echo "<p>\"$car\"</p>";
        echo "<p>Description: $descr</p>";
        echo "<p>Price: $price</p>";
        echo "<p>Manufacturer: $manuf</p>";
        echo "<p>Picture: $pic</p>";
        echo "<p>Name: $name</p>";
        echo "<p>Distance: $dist</p>";

        mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
        <br><br>
        <a href="newcar.html">Insert another car</a>
        <br>
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I actually fixed it by removing 'basename' from the $target_file variable and changed BLOB in database to TEXT.. Then I fetched the tmp_name uploading it to folder and the name to the database. My description above was a bit confusing I apologize, I wanted the file (picture) to be saved into a folder and the pic name saved in database, then posting it via database.